# Issue comparing strings to button text

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)
>   [spinner If Strings** == not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000893/spinner-if-strings-not-working)

```
public void btnRecordTrip_Clicked(View v)
{
    Button b = (Button)v;
    String currentText = b.getText().toString();
    if (currentText == "Record Trip")
```

The value of currentText is "Record Trip" yet the it compares unequal.  I tried .trim() with the same result.  The two strings are equal but they compare unequal.  What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.equals()` to compare strings in Java

```
if (currentText.equals("Record Trip"))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, when you are comparing objects, `==` operator is used for identity check. For equality check you should use `.equals()` method.

In your case, even though the two string objects are equal value wise, they are two different objects.

Comment: Does this also go for checking equality on Integers, Booleans, etc?  In other words should "==" never be used for checking for equal value?

Comment: @user1058647: " In other words should "==" never be used for checking for equal value?", Yes, in case of objects.